# How does the Starbucks passbook pass show an installed app banner?

Tags: ios, passbook, passkit

We are trying to figure out how to add an installed app banner to the back of our Passbook passes, just like the Starbucks app does, but I can't find any documentation or mention of this feature anywhere.

[image]

There doesn't appear to be anything pertaining to this in the Starbucks pass file itself. At first I thought it was simply automatic based on the pass type identifier, but our app is registered as a handler of the pass type identifier, yet still does not show up in an app banner on the back of cards generated with that identifier.

Does anyone know how to utilize this (apparently undocumented) feature of Passbook?

Comment: Is this on the back of the pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your app's id to pass.json top-level key **associatedStoreIdentifiers**, e.g.

```
{
    ...
    "associatedStoreIdentifiers": [1234567890],
    ...
}
```

It's documented in [Passbook Package Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW7)

Comment: Ah thanks. I must have missed that. Odd that it uses an app store id instead of a bundle id or pass type id.